# Uploading file with predefined file format

Tags: asp.net, .net

In a .Net Web Application, a `xls` file needs to be uploaded.

The required scenario is like: when the user clicks on a button (say, Browse button) on a page, it'd open the file browse window.

Here, is it possible to show only the available excel file(s), so that the user can select any of the excel file listed there?

Can this be acheived programatically

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

There is no way to control the file spec for the file browser from within a web browser. You can't use JavaScript either on the file input value.

The normal solution is to look at the file extension on the server side, after it has been posted and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex expression as below:

<asp:FileUpload ID="fuImportData" runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidator" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="fuImportData"
     ErrorMessage="Only XLS are allowed" 
     ValidationExpression="(.*.([Xx][Ll][Ss])$)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: Yes. This is for validation purpose.